# Вычислить среднее значение заданной последовательности целых чисел

Tags: java

Помогите пожалуйста вычислить среднее целочисленное значение заданной последовательности целых чисел  длиной до 100 значений и заканчивающееся на 0. Даже не понимаю куда тут 100 вставлять.

Завершите код, чтобы вычислить среднее значение заданной последовательности чисел.
Последовательность состоит из целых значений. Он может иметь длину до 100 значений и заканчивается на 0.
Среднее значение также является целым числом . Используйте целочисленные операции.
Получите последовательность чисел из стандартного ввода и распечатайте результат на стандартный вывод.

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int count = 0;
    while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        count++;
        if (scanner.nextInt() == 0) break;
    }
    int[] array = new int[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        if (array[i] == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        sum += array[i];
    }
    int average = sum / count;
    System.out.println(average);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
int[] array = new int[100];
int count = 0;
int t;
int sum = 0
while (count < 100){ 
    int t = scanner.nextInt();
    if (t == 0) 
        break;
    else {
        a[count] = t;
        sum += t;
        count++;
    }
}
```